# I keep getting an error when i try to select an element from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying  to select an element from a drop down menu using selenium and Python. The element I want to select is the Expiration month and Year of a debit card. Whenever I run my code it throws this error message:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clear'

This is the code i used:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,   delay).until(ec.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID,'ExpirationDateMonth'),"4"))
print("page is ready")
except TimeoutException:
print("Loading took too much time")                               

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ExpirationDateMonth'))
select.select_by_index

wait.clear()
wait.click()
wait.sendkeys('4')
print(wait)
time.sleep(11)
driver.close();
```

'''html

```
*</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
            <label for="ExpirationDate" class="control-label">Expiration Date</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ExpirationDate">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <label class="control-label" for="ExpirationDateMonth"> Month</label>
                <select id="ExpirationDateMonth" class="form-control form-control-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedExpirationDateMonth field is required." name="CardPayment.SelectedExpirationDateMonth"><optgroup label="Expiration Date Month"></optgroup><option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option selected="selected">3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <label class="control-label" for="ExpirationDateYear"> Year </label>
                <select id="ExpirationDateYear" class="form-control form-control-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedExpirationDateYear field is required." name="CardPayment.SelectedExpirationDateYear"><optgroup label="Expiration Date Year"></optgroup><option>2020</option>
<option>2021</option>
<option>2022</option>
<option>2023</option>
<option>2024</option>
<option>2025</option>
<option>2026</option>
<option>2027</option>
<option>2028</option>
<option>2029</option>
<option>2030</option>
<option>2031</option>
<option>2032</option>
<option>2033</option>
<option>2034</option>
<option>2035</option>
<option>2036</option>
<option>2037</option>
<option>2038</option>
<option>2039</option>
<option>2040</option>
<option>2041</option>
<option>2042</option>
<option>2043</option>
<option>2044</option>
</select>
            </div>*
```

I tried this code

````py
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]'))
select.select_by_value("12")

And it gave me this error

  NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-7-d8a234e99906> in <module>
        104 # select = Select(driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]")));
        105 select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]'))
    --> 106 select.select_by_value("12")
        107 
        108 # select = Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]")));

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in select_by_value(self, value)
         85             matched = True
         86         if not matched:
    ---> 87             raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
         88 
         89     def select_by_index(self, index):

    NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 12


I also tried this:

    select = Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]')));
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("Value12");

And It gave me this error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e85af3dd3041> in <module>
    106 # select.select_by_value("12")
    107 
--> 108 select = Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]')));
    109 select.deselectAll();
    110 select.selectByVisibleText("Value12");

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'


I tried the code you sent me in my code:
```python
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ExpirationDateMonth"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text('12')




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pkgd.png
````

Comment: wait.clear() is not valid.

Comment: Also what Is the website?

Comment: The web site is https://www.alltranfinancialpay.com/

Comment: Since it's inaccessible due to a login credential. Can you post the html of the tag you want to use.

Comment: select.select_by_visible_text('12') try that

Comment: I tried the code you sent and the good thing is it is not throwing an error message anymore. Now, what it does is, it highlights the Expiration Date for the Month drop down field without bringing up the values. I sent a link to the screen shot. Thank you

Comment: @arundeepchohan I tried the code you sent and the good thing is it is not throwing an error message anymore. Now, what it does is, it highlights the Expiration Date for the Month drop down field without bringing up the values. I sent a link to the screen shot. Thank you

Comment: I also attached a screen shot of the Expiration Date(Month and Year). The screen shot shows how the month gets highlighted after running my code. Thanks

Comment: print select.first_selected_option.text  if you want it's value

Comment: @arundeepchohan I got the value 12, but i am still not able to select the value i want from the expiration date drop down.

Comment: Just repeat the above for the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
select.select_by_visible_text('12')
print select.first_selected_option.text if you want it's value
```

To select the option 12 and than use the one you selected first grab it by its text value and than print the one selected.